# Ontology and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification

this is a newbie question, so be tolerant.
I have a dataset of people who bought products, and those products are under a "text" classification.
I have Music, Games, Books, and so on as categories.

What I like to do is to reclassify the product in a way where "Book" may be "Book -> war -> with alien", afaik this is something named ontology.

The possible subcategories are already defined, however, they are not year connected.

How to proceed to have this done in an automatic way?

Comment: What information do you have available for the reclassification and how are the subclasses to be determined?

Comment: I know who bought what, the title of the content, and somehow the existing hierarchical category structure.  What do you mean with subclasses?

Comment: If "war" and "alien" are not subclasses of "book," then what would they be?

Comment: Ok, I got your point, I think that is something that must be defined, and likely by hand. Once I have the subclasses, how do I proceed?

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for.  If you truly have definitions, apply them.  But that's not a problem of stats or machine learning, so I would guess that you somehow want to infer these classifications from data -- but what data?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to use machine learning to build an ontology. Are there any algorithms that allow helping in such tasks?